# react how to guarantee I have received data from api before proceeding?

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a simple react app that looks like this

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
   const [dataFromAPI, setDataFromAPI] = useState<any>(null);

   const getData = () => {
    d3.json(url)
      .then((data: any) => {
        console.log("data from d3", data);
        setDataFromAPI(data);
      })
      .catch((err: Error) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
   };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

//wait for the state to be changed before proceeding

return (
   <div className="App">
     <DataVisualisation data={dataFromAPI} />
   </div>
  );
};
```

But the problem is that the property gets passed before data has actually been received. My question is how can i guarantee that I have received the data before it gets passed as a prop?

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally render the component `DataVisualisation` will prevent the empty data to pass through props.

```
{dataFromAPI && <DataVisualisation data={dataFromAPI} />}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        {dataFromAPI != null &&
            <DataVisualisation data={dataFromAPI} />
        }
    </div>
    );
 };
```

Try this

Comment: Idk, it doesn't seem to work for me. The propgram doesn't crash now, but i don't get a visualisation of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the shortcircuit approach i.e.

```
 return (
   <div className="App">
      {dataFromAPI && <DataVisualisation data={dataFromAPI} />}
   </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach and see if it works.
**It works fine for me.**

```
return (
<div className='App'>
   {dataFromApi? <DataVisualization data={dataFromAPI} /> :null}
</div>
 );
```